# Safari-Extension: Add HTTP Headers

Tags: http-headers, safari-extension

I've written an extension for Chrome which allows to send some authentification headers for an internal system. Now some colleagues asked me if I could provide this addon for Safari as well. My addon also includes some kind of internal adress book to search persons in our company.

While the adress book functionality works fine in Safari, I can't find a way to add some HTTP Headers (I don't need to manipulate existing Headers, just add some more Attributes like `USERID`). Is this possible with Safari?